# Pass data from one div to another without using hidden control

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a php template in word press. On page load it is showing first div and hiding another (shown in script below) and on click of another button in first div it is hiding itself and showing the hidden div. From the first div ,i have entered values (in its fields)and on second div also i have entered values . At the submit of the last div i want to store values of all the values in a table .

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".upload").hide();
jQuery(".order").show();

   jQuery(".order-btn").click(function(){
       jQuery(".order").fadeOut(1000);
       jQuery(".upload").fadeIn(1000);

   });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: You mean form right, not div? You want to do AJAX is this what you mean?

Comment: i mean in div not in form .......yeah ajax will work

Comment: Have any idea then please share here

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - btw div doesn't have "fields", but form does.

Comment: inside a div we can write <div><input type="text"> </div>

Comment: Of course you can. You can wrap your inputs with whatever you want it doesn't have any relevance - you're submitting a **form** not a **div**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap all your dives into `<form>` tag and than you'll be able to get values in form-action page, or if you use Ajax, then, you'll just serialize your form and sent in request to action page, the result will be the same.

Also please separate your Js files from template and use `<link>` tag to add it in html document.